# How to stop webview from eating up the whole screen on loadUrl()?

Tags: button, webview, visible

Below is my XML layout file. I "loadURL()" in "OnCreate()" ...
That means when the activity starts up the first thing I see is the website ...

I cannot see the buttons whatsoever, The webView simply eats up the entire page, I tried relative layout, linear, scrollview, I even explicitly made the layout_width and height of the freaking webView to "10dp" each ...Still it eats up the entire screen, and nothing else is visible.

It's either buttons +webview(without URL)
or 
No buttons + webview(with URL opened)

I want the buttons to stay fixed at the top...and below them a normal WebView .... It should just leave some space for the buttons to be actually visible...

:/

How to do this ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="load"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

     <WebView
        android:id="@+id/ww"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop webview from taking up the whole screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030293/how-to-stop-webview-from-taking-up-the-whole-screen)

Answer (score 3):

In your WebView layout element, use `wrap_content` (instead of `match_parent`):

```
 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/ww"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```